# Why am I unable to view my Flask-Admin pages on Heroku?

Tags: python, heroku, flask, flask-admin

I have a Flask application that I am attempting to deploy onto Heroku. I have two problems that are stopping me from deploying. The first is that when I run the command `heroku local`. I am taken to my `localhost:5000/` page in which everything looks fine until I head to my `/admin/login` page. The second is that heroku can't seem to detect the `heroku/python` build pack. I don't know if the first problem is related to the second.

For that page I get a `500 error` and additionally there are no logs on the command line to view. All I see is this:

```
⇒  heroku local
   forego | starting web.1 on port 5000
   web.1  | [2015-12-03 12:31:42 -0500] [7200] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.4.1
   web.1  | [2015-12-03 12:31:42 -0500] [7200] [INFO] Listening at:      
   http://0.0.0.0:5000 (7200)
   web.1  | [2015-12-03 12:31:42 -0500] [7200] [INFO] Using worker: sync
   web.1  | [2015-12-03 12:31:42 -0500] [7203] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 7203
```

I can't determine if I'm supposed to see something on that page or if my Procfile is somehow not allowing it. Anyways, this is my directory structure:

```
~/Desktop/project_directory
    /venv
       / static
         /images, javascript, css, etc.
       / templates
         - html files
       / bin
       / include
       / migrations
       - Procfile
       - alembic.ini
       - blackduck_directory.py
       - blackduck_directory.pyc
       - pip-selfcheck.json
       - requirements.txt
       - runtime.txt
```

This is the content of my `Procfile`:

```
web: gunicorn blackduck_directory:app --log-file=-
```

This is my runtime.txt:

```
python-2.7.10
```

This is my requirements.txt:

```
alembic==0.7.7
bcrypt==2.0.0
blinker==1.4
cffi==1.3.1
dominate==2.1.16
Flask==0.10.1
Flask-Admin==1.3.0
Flask-Bcrypt==0.7.1
Flask-Login==0.3.2
Flask-Mail==0.9.1
Flask-Migrate==1.6.0
Flask-Principal==0.4.0
Flask-Script==2.0.5
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.1
Flask-WTF==0.12
gunicorn==19.4.1
itsdangerous==0.24
Jinja2==2.8
Mako==1.0.2
MarkupSafe==0.23
passlib==1.6.5
Pillow==3.0.0
psycopg2==2.6.1
pycparser==2.14
python-editor==0.4
six==1.10.0
SQLAlchemy==1.0.9
visitor==0.1.2
Werkzeug==0.11.2
wheel==0.24.0
WTForms==2.0.2
```

There is a question on stackoverflow [Heroku with Flask-Admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30422280/flask-admin-not-working-in-heroku). Has anyone encountered this problem? Otherwise running `python blackduck_directory.py` works properly.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. I removed app.secret_key 'secret_key' from my application. That's why it wasn't working.